# Can I use generic repository type for npm registry?

Tags: artifactory

We are currently in the process of purchasing a license of Artifactory Pro, but the procurement process takes time in our organization. In order to build knowledge around Artifactory and NPM to use Artifactory, is there a way to front the NPM Registry with Artifactory using a Generic Repository Type?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you would like to use the NPM client with Artifactory, you will have to use the [NPM repository type](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Npm+Registry) and not the Generic Repository Type.
You wont be able to use the Generic Repository Type with the NPM client, as the Generic Repository Type does not calculate metadata / index artifacts.
To configuring your NPM client to work with the NPM repository type, you may use the [Artifactory Set me up](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/General+Information#GeneralInformation-SetMeUp) functionality which will guide you how to configure the NPM client